# Limit text field to specific length

Tags: 7

In my custom content type, I want restricted the length of text entered in a text field. I want to check whether a user entered e.g. thousands of words. For this I tried this one but unable to achieve.

```
$my_field = field_get_items('node',node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE), 'my_field');
$my_field = substr($my_field,0,100).'...';
print $my_field[0]['value'];
```

Is there any way to do this in drupal 7 context?

Answer (score 4):

If you're really trying to restrict the character count at the point of entry you need to set the field in your form to have a [#maxlength](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#maxlength) in your form definition.

Comment: I want to restrict the text on one page but when clicked on `more link` or `read more` then the detail text should be displayed on next page.

Comment: Oh!  That's quite different to restricting the length of a field at the point of input. Take a look at the `Manage Display` tab for that content type and set the Teaser display to `trimmed` or similar.  There's a very good module called [Smart Trim](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_trim) which can help customise the snippet too.

Comment: Thanku @Darvanen, I did it using php `strlen()` and `substr()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is basically two modules that come to my mind regarding this functionality. The second one ([Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength)) is probably a bit more promissing:

- [Webform Countdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_countdown) *"Provides a textarea component for Drupal webforms with a configurable, twitter-style dynamic word or character count."*
- [Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) *"When the maximum length is enforced for a field, while editing content of that type some Java Script will countdown how many characters are left, also if the Javascript is turned off, it falls back to form API validation."*

[EDIT] If you instead want to limit the text length shown in a teaser view, you can do that through the basic display settings of your content type:

`structure > content types > my_content_type > display > teaser`

There you can set the format to "Trimmed" or "Summary or trimmed" and then  limit the lenght for example to 600: `"Trim length: 600"`. Afaik this setting can be adjusted in every view.

Comment: Thanku @tillinberlin, actually I want to restrict the text on one page but when clicked on `more link` or `read more` then the detail text should be displayed on next page.

Comment: ok, i see – I edited my answer accordingly